Title: ASP.NET Core Cookie Not Being Set in Chrome Due to Invalid SSL Certificate
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application where I'm facing an issue with cookies not being set properly in Chrome. After logging in, I notice that the Set-Cookie header is included in the response, but the cookie is not actually stored by the browser.
Here is the relevant Set-Cookie header from the response:
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8Jm87cUOqpRDo6_9RD1HLnFCdP2L-Djs51nmMolX5ygKHiN2EIi5TWFf56VrQiIEQcXiZtUt3toiRqU0BKUWLW6UXVt2a7jjZR6v9GGSqY4PS7Rd-HKZS_xe3StTLb5TjeqLHiipez_EbFMfufo7y15kFXYRw0WORR0HP6a-OV3C_5oL7tLjTNdpm-eLdqzSZ4SlSnDBRvZi5tvQW2WM5HVyHaTK3S3jgVeolOsfNGuDihymCggmE1FGyZHPB0MTLmKxB3EZ4LELL9DmduwFZYFP1oDlPdHnugHPqwaeXTLBNhA5_MVVvQnouVBwNdWwmGmFZ-830EPL_t-SFjO-iO0NIhOhxDivDrzCHKPXP_ad4M9k_2hCN3hhnyRWca1wwFxQ8MRgfVRbyqeYt3cA3jn_hUXyequoxj6ImUlW_b6pUKPZJ8TYyEu8uvyIw9ndaNj74SAg9zTUxBI0iTN2HOWX0qD8XyEFStQJO7zVXUIgm54AyTgMfVyWMqoqkktZbt0moMKQZ1G9HBsbjFAez7tdygbxl25MkeaIlrg14qNYnksRXfCz9AzqTtxblnVS4Om6smC4AVKC7eqyr-CIU-ej6_3GRaSj8vxGM9cuCdW_3uTw_6wKduspm4pDtTKQ6qvXylTPwmAHUIL-ZMg0JHF7pj6dYRWclZ3kGYI15KvJCsXOrZvSp0JYmE20AYZEd4QIazaP9KNxOP4LmlRawsDIrud1kkMLpEmfENwLXTfaTEmielNY3qIRgBkjWA6m5I_O7WZsIvcvG_VETB1ZUM4WbZNWkr4Nm5z0ag0wjLq9eZjFr5mDDRWdJjfqqP3jmK5vrbFMI6q6H0Ra5faVOrJBk5ymnDO7-8nOYHv0Yayrld3-KklOuq4b7kG54qnEHkqwuEPbgSlFIZXSUU6Jiky0yjVI7nHlgneUwC0CU805WJ_8vP9ivX1QAC2-4GiqsQ; expires=Wed, 21 Aug 2024 08:34:41 GMT; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly

A few important details:
The SameSite attribute is set to Lax.
The cookie is marked as HttpOnly.
The site is using an SSL certificate, but it is not a valid one.

Despite these settings, the cookie is not being stored in Chrome. The same issue does not appear in other browsers. I have already tried clearing the browser cache and cookies, and the issue persists.
Could the invalid SSL certificate be causing Chrome to reject the cookie? What would be the best way to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I don't have an answer, but it seems reasonable to refuse to set the cookie if the cert is invalid.  (could mean DNS/HOSTS file has been modified and would allow a possibly malicious IP to set cookies for the real domain...)

I have two domains: one is used as a staging environment, and the other is the main domain for the production server. There is no issue with the main server, but I'm facing a problem with the staging server, which has an invalid certificate. The key point is that this issue has only recently appeared and is only visible in Chrome.

you might try using a self-signed cert for the staging server.  (when testing you'll be prompted to add trust for it)
